# Use typecast or use trailing data type identifier. (uint16_t)10 or 10u?

Tags: c

In order to come up with a right answer when a subtract operation of  different data type operands in a 16 bit machine (please see the code below), I understand that changing `10` to `10u` will provide a right answer.

I am used to typecasting instead of using trailing data type identifier: Use `(uint16_t)10` instead of `10u`.

What will be the preferred way?

I understand that `10u` is a lot less to type.
Besides the benefit of less typing, is there a significant reason why `10u` is a much better way?  Or it really doesn't matter?

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t   u16c;
int32_t    s32;

int main()
{

    u16c = 100U;
    s32  = 10 - u16c;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different results in 16 bit int machine(MSP430) and 32 bit int machine(ARM CORTEX) in a subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081308/different-results-in-16-bit-int-machinemsp430-and-32-bit-int-machinearm-corte)

Comment: "Use (uint16_t)10 instead of 10u." - assuming `10` is just one possible value, that's not necessarily the same! And your typedefs are bad practice. If you don't need specific names, use the standard types. Said that: what is your **actual** problem? As this is clearly the same question you already asked, I'd recommend you should get the basics right. Read a good C book, get familiar with the standard if you want to dig that deep. C is no language to learn by trial&error!

Comment: @Olaf - This question focuses on the preferred way of representing 10 as unsigned int rather than why the subtract operation brings wrong answer.

Comment: @Olaf - There are no new data types which I defined.  `uint16_t` and `int32_t` are defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: @Nguaial, you seem to be missing the point: **the two options you present are not alternatives of each other**.  They mean different things.  In some cases, on some systems, those different meanings happen to coincide, but you should not take such a coincidence as an excuse interchange them.  You should use the one that has the meaning you want -- and we cannot tell you which that is, because you have not told us what it it is you want.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - This is  a corollary to one of the answers that were provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081308/different-results-in-16-bit-int-machinemsp430-and-32-bit-int-machinearm-corte).  I just  wanted to know which is a preferred way of making `10` to `unsgined int`.

Comment: Assuming you want `s32` to end up with the value −90 and that `int` is 16 bits wide, `s32 = 10u - u16u;` produces the correct answer and `s32 = (uint16_t)10 - u16u;` produces the wrong answer. You should _really_ be asking whether `(unsigned)10` or `10u` is preferred.

Comment: @lan Abbott - Here is the link.  It runs fine.[link](http://ideone.com/42DD0P)

Comment: ……@IanAbbott: Conversion of unsigned to signed integers is implementation defined. It is not guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `unsigned` is not generally synonymous with any particular fixed-sized type.  The expression `10u` will yield type `unsigned` regardless of the size of `unsigned`, while the expression `(uint16_t)n` will yield unsigned value on platforms where `int` cannot represent all values 0-65535, or a signed value on platforms where it can.  This can be critically important in situations like:

```
unsigned mul_mod_65536(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{ return (x*y) & 65535u; }
```

Some compilers for 32-bit systems will generate code that malfunctions in
some cases where the product of x and y exceeds 2147483647, even if the
bottom 16 bits from the hardware' multiply instruction would be correct.
The code may be corrected by writing it as:

```
unsigned mul_mod_65536(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
{ return (1u*x*y) & 65535u; }
```

Note that casting 1 to (uint16_t) wouldn't fix anything, since that would
simply get converted back to signed `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer - just too long for a comment.

The problem with casting is that it hides warnings that the compiler would pick out.  For instance

```
uint16_t x = (uint16_t) 70000;  /* No warning */
uint16_t y = (uint16_t) -1;     /* No warning */
uint16_t z = 70000U;            /* Compiler warning */
uint16_t a = -1;                /* Compiler warning */
```

It gets a lot worse when you are converting to Unicode.  Maybe you ought to read casts as **I think I know what I'm doing**